# Yaris 2003, headlight motor cable

Tags: toyota, yaris

I have a 2003 Yaris. In 2012 I changed the headlights by buying them online, they work perfectly until today, but the electrical input that powers the positioning motor is diverged from the cable I have in the car. You know if there are adapters, I would like to solve this little thing.

My Yaris is Italian and maybe the Japanese headlights.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the headlights are from a different year, then the connectors got changed.

So, find the matching connectors and then make the adjustments to connect the wires appropriately.

Comment: I'm looking for a connector, an adapter or the headlight connector so as to rewire

Comment: I'll re-state : "So, find the matching connectors and then make the adjustments to connect the wires appropriately."...

Comment: ! Even if you repeat your answer, go around my question, don't answer.

Comment: @BOES As a trained vehicle electrician, I do have other suggestions, but following your advice I won't go there.